# C++ Unordered Set string hash time complexity?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, set, unordered-set

Why the worst case complexity of insert into set is linear constant of size of container and not the size of element itself?

I am specifically talking about string. If I have a string set of size m, then if I insert a new string of size x, I assume that the insert operation will need to read string of size x in order to calculate key? So why dont we consider that time?

If there is another string that is of size 1000*x, then insertion will still take m size in worst case?
Regardless of size of string, the time is 0(m)? How?

Comment: So why dont we consider that time? Because it's a "constant" time.  Yes, strings will have different sizes so the function might take a little more or less time, but on average it will have the same amount of time per insert so it can be ignored.  In most other cases, hashing will always happen in a constant time, take hashing an `int` for example, so in general the has function is just some constant added to each `N` and is factored out.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth making a `hashed_string` class that contains a `std::string` along with its hash value and providing a hashing function that uses the stored hash value.

Comment: so I the hashing function used by STL does not read the entire string or does it read it in parallel? Because reading entire string takes 0(n) time , where n is length of string and I assume to generate hashKey, STL needs to read the entire string. Just getting my head straight with this confusion.

Comment: For MSVC it's linear: [hash](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1a20fe1133d711a647bbb135d98743f91b7be323/stl/inc/xstring#L5200) -> [_Hash_array_representation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1a20fe1133d711a647bbb135d98743f91b7be323/stl/inc/type_traits#L2149) -> [_Fnv1a_append_bytes](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1a20fe1133d711a647bbb135d98743f91b7be323/stl/inc/type_traits#L2119)

Comment: Doubling the number of elements doesn’t affect the time to hash an element. It increases the time needed to insert all the elements, and that’s what time complexity is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a great question and it hits at some nuances in the way we analyze the cost of operations on hash tables.

There are actually several different ways to think about this. The first one is to think about the runtimes of the operations on a hash table measured with a runtime perspective that purely focuses on the size of the table. From that perspective, the cost of an insertion, lookup, or deletion does not scale *as a function of the number of table elements*. That is, the cost of looking something up does not depend on the number of elements in the table, the cost of inserting an element doesn't depend on the number of elements in the table, etc. From that vantage point, if we let *n* denote the number of elements in the table, then the cost of an insertion, deletion, or lookup is O(1), because there is no dependency on *n*.

In this sense, the big-O notation here is meant to be interpreted as "if the only variable is *n*, the number of elements in the table, how will things scale?" But that leaves a lot to be desired, since it completely ignores the cost of comparing strings for equality, the cost of evaluating the hash function, etc.

If you factor those details in, then yes, you're correct - the cost of looking up, inserting, or deleting a string of length *m* from a hash table with *n* elements is O(*m*), not O(1).

The perspective I've always found most helpful is the following. When a hash table says that all operations run in time O(1), what it really means is that each operation requires only O(1) total hash evaluations and comparisons. In that sense, it means "the cost of looking something up, or inserting something, or deleting something is some constant number of hash evaluations and comparisons." To then work out the total cost, you then multiply O(1) by the cost of a hash or comparison, which in the case of strings of length *m* would be O(*m*). That gives you the overall runtime of O(*m*), which matches your intuition.

Answer (score 2):

The standard gives the complexity as a function of the number of elements in the container *in terms of primitive operations on the element type*. These primitive operations are supplied by the instantiation.

> All of the complexity requirements in this Clause are stated solely in terms of the number of operations on
> the contained objects. [Example: The copy constructor of type `vector<vector<int>>` has linear complexity,
> even though the complexity of copying each contained `vector<int>` is itself linear. — end example]

For example here's how the complexity of `operator==` on unordered associative containers is described:

> For unordered_set and unordered_map, the complexity of operator== (i.e., **the number of calls** to the `==` operator of the `value_type`, to the predicate returned by `key_eq()`, and to the hasher returned by `hash_function()`) is proportional to N in the average case and to N<sup>2</sup> in the worst case, where N is `a.size()`.

If you require complexity in terms of other operations, such as small integer arithmetic operations, you can derive it yourself if you know the complexity of each operation on the element type in those terms.